ui-router transition params contains the hash-bang
I'm updating my web application to a newer version of angularJs (from 1.5 to 1.8) and ui-router (from 0.2 to the latest available).
After those updates, $stateParams, which I use to handle query params, is deprecated. So, i had to switch to the $transition$ directive. With that, I've got a problem. Either then the correct query params, it also get the hash-bang parameter, which was not recovered with $stateParams.
This is an example of the url generated by my application:
http://example.net/APP-NAME/#!/home/dashboard
How is it possible?
To give you an example of how I'm currently working on this, this is a piece of code that I currently paste over all the project to handle this additional param:

  let param= Object.assign({}, $transition$.params());
  delete param['#'];


And it works like a charm, but it's spreaded in all the project.
I've also tried to handle the transition parameters before landing on each pages via transition events, but it doesn't work.
$transitions.onSuccess({},function (transition) {
    let toState = transition.to();
    let state = transition.router.stateService;
    let fromState = transition.from();
    let toParams = transition.params();
    let fromParams = transition.params('from');
        if('#' in toParams){
        let newParams = Object.assign({}, toParams);
        delete newParams['#'];
        return state.go(toState, newParams);
    }
});

I've also tried to insert this piece of code inside the onBefore event, but the trasition will be rejected.
